# session time-out jax-rs

Tags: rest, servlets, jax-rs, session-timeout

Does it make sense do define session-timeout with restful web services like jax-rs? For what I know the rest is stateless (or should be stateless) so what the point of storing a session?
If I don't define the session-timeout in the configuration file web.xml for how long session will be stored in servlet container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically REST should be stateless and you should not create a session for the rest calls.

If you don't specify the session timeout, it uses the default one specified by the container. In tomcat the default is 30 minutes.